# How can delete a row?

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Remove a specific table row using jQuery.</title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="r1">
    <td>Rahul</td>
    <td>Sethi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="r2">
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>Rayy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

  <p> <input id="button1" type="button" value="Click to remove 2nd Row." /></p>
</body>
</html>

js:-
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#button1').click(function(){ 
   $('#r2').remove(); 
   });
});
```

If any record entry is deleted from the list then it should be removed from the entry list instead it is just hiding. if we increment the list count from show entry list box then the deleted entry will also appears in the list.

Comment: What do you mean by entry list?

Comment: then you need ajax to remove it from db too

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy ,the entry list means the table in which data's added

Comment: @Anant ,  no database entry its is temporarily displaying,